# regular expression gives different output in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My problem is that when I use this code:

```
var queuediv = document.getElementById('MSO_ContentTable');
var total = get_text(queuediv);
countTotal = total.split(/\s+/).length;
```

this is the function

```
function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);

        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

it gives me different values in IE and other browser gives same value. So is there a problem with my regexp?

Thanks.

Comment: What input are you using for this regex?

Comment: var total = get_text(queuediv);

Comment: this is the function         function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);

        }
    }
    return ret;
}

Comment: what does `get_text()` exactly do? Seems to be a problem with HTML that is returned from the browser. It may contain a different number of line breaks which fall into `\s`.

Comment: @VbPatel Please use JSFiddle to publish your code. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: plz tell me what chang required in regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting by **white space** characters (line breaks, tabs ...). These seems to vary in DOM representation of different browsers. I assume you are trying to split words. Try:

```
total.split(/ /).length;
```

or

```
total.replace(/\n\r\f/, '').split(/\s/).length
```

you may replace `\v` and `\t` also.

Comment: thanks daniel you code total.split(/ /).length; is working like a charm all browser gives same output but the count is wrong.

Comment: they add two or more spaces in count is there other regexp plz suggest me