# regular expression not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression gives different output in FF and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440436/regular-expression-gives-different-output-in-ff-and-ie)

I use following code

```
function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);

        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var queuediv = document.getElementById('MSO_ContentTable');
var total = get_text(queuediv);
countTotal = total.split(/\s+/).length;
alert(countTotal);
```

the div contains text:-

```
You can get started       fdfd                       erfd            dsff
```

the code gives me output:-26
Note:- Chrome and Fx gives output 7 but IE gives 26. I think the problem is in the regular expression. This regex is not working in IE I think

Comment: my div has text u shown which contain more then one spaces but in above its look like one space so keep in mind plz

Comment: Why `get_text()` function instead of `textContent || innerText` ?

Comment: get_text() because my div contain other HTML tag. i retrieve all content from html tag

Comment: "Not working as expected" is better that "Not working". Always assume it is you who do not do it right

Comment: @VbPatel: I mean if you want the text nodes serialised together, just use `var text = element.textContent || element.innerText`.

Comment: Please don't post the [exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440436/regular-expression-gives-different-output-in-ff-and-ie), [all the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422355/javascript-split-function-not-working-in-ie) with different wording.

Comment: @alex: tanks alex u r right but my problem in count word length

Comment: 7 seems correct. Do an alert(total); in IE, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well regular expressions aren't actually standardized and some tools do use \+ instead of + for the greedy version of the quantifier. You could try that in IE and see what the results are and then have conditional code to make it work in IE (imagine that).

Comment: thanks for reply but still it's not working my requirement is to count all the words in div so for that suggest me all  regexp

Comment: I guess I would try things like the following:
1. Try \s* instead of \s+ 
2. try \W+ instead of \s+ and see if the result varies
3. Capture the results of the Split into String[], Trim() each entry and if its length is 0 remove decrement the count
I'm assuming in your example there were a total of 25 spaces and that IE was not doing the proper greedy capture but capturing each one.